# Does long running process locks aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp, iis-7.5, shared-hosting

I am using VS2010 for development and  ftp 3.10 64 bit for Uploading file to shared server, OS is Win 8 .

I have created a web application (asp.net web form) in dot net 4.0. The application uploads some file,sends email etc.As large file will be uploaded I had given executiontimeout as 1 hour.

Now every thing was running smooth but I updated the site using FTP but when I am doing this I am getting Error

**Response: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
Error:  Critical file transfer error**

So I want to known that If i stop a site from running and use FTP to upload my file If any process is running does it stop with website or not
and 
Does long running process locks aspx pages

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So two questions. I'll answer "If any process is running does it stop with website or not?"

That depends how you stop it. Generally, the application pool associated with your site will try to shut down cleanly. IIS will stop any more requests being sent to the app pool and existing requests will be allowed to finish. Once they've finished, the apppool will shut down. I'd be surprised if you could take more substantial action using a shared host.

Would you really want you code to be terminated at any random point? Sounds dangerous to me...

Comment: so it means if the process is running in the back ground it can lock the resources it is been using in my case aspx file am i right