# IIS web application - The Process Cannot Access the File Because it is Being Used by Another Process

Tags: asp.net, iis, updates

I have a web application on server that is using.
I Update application on my computer  , but when I copy files from My local computer to server AND run application I get error "IIS - The Process Cannot Access the File Because it is Being Used by Another Process" then I can't update on server and use new version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does long running process locks aspx pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004022/does-long-running-process-locks-aspx-pages)

Comment: Generally speaking, that's expected. Before updating a site on IIS, you should stop it first.